# bootstrap dropdown nav over/underlap over content below

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This may be tricky to answer/explain properly but:

Building small website for school project. Using bootstrap. When screen is below 780px the nav bar turns into the mobile design with the button icon when clicked has the dropdown menu.

The issue is the menu is meant to push content under it down when its open but it is just going over my content on some page/ under a slideshow i have on main page and it is unclickable as the content sits over it.

I've tried to include all relevant code, it is a complete mess however. Because of all the HTML/CSS and bootstrap and jquery links it's too hard to post in a jfiddle.

Can anyone see anything that would be wrong??

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JHnn.jpg

HTML:

```
    <!-- Start of nav bar -->
    <div class="bottomHeader">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>


            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                 <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>   
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Services<span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>                  
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Deals<span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>

                <li class="dropdown searchDropDown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Search<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><form role="search">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control searchBox" placeholder="Search">

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
                <!-- SEARCH BUTTON -->
                <div class="searchSection">              
                <form class="searchRight" role="search">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control searchBox" placeholder="Search">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                </div>   

            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div> <!-- end bottom header div -->   
    </div> <!-- end header div -->



    </header>

    <!-- START OF PAGE CONTENT -->
    <content>

    <div class="background">
        <div class="container2">
            <div class="trial"> BOO<br>BOO<br>BOO<br>BOO<br>BOO<br>BOO<br>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    </content>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.headerBox {
  background-color: #0076a3;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 115px;
}

.topHeader {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.dellImgBox {
  padding-left: 42px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.socialMediaBox {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 53px;
  padding-top: 5px; 
}

.smImg {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.smImgLeft {margin-left: 30px;}

.socialMediaBox a:hover {
  background: transparent;
}

/******* Bottom Header ********/
.bottomHeader {
  border: 0px solid black;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 53px;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px;
}
.navbar-header {
  float: right;
}

.trial {
  margin: 20px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 300px;
  color: #444;
}


/* Have nav on right position & display DDmenu */
@media screen and (min-width: 772px) {
  .container > .navbar-header,
  .container-fluid > .navbar-header,
  .container > .navbar-collapse,
  .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: -13px;
  }
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 771px) {
  .topHeader {display:none;}
  .headerBox {height: 55px;}
  ul.nav.navbar-nav {width: 260px;}
}

/* Hide Main Search input field @ Xwidth */
@media screen and (max-width: 882px) {
  .searchSection {display: none;}
  .searchDropDown {display: block;} 
}
@media screen and (min-width: 883px) {
    .searchDropDown {
    display: none!important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS file you should remove `height: 53px;` and it will work.

```
.bottomHeader {
  border: 0px solid black;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 53px;
}
```

Change to this one:

```
.bottomHeader {
  border: 0px solid black;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to work @Vahid here is a more relevant screen shot i think http://imgur.com/CB1HYpq 

The menu is hidden behind the slideshow, and it also does this on other pages just over plain text /div area

Comment: I mean you should remove this line: **height: 53px;** . It's working. see: http://i.imgur.com/ebt1EZu.png

Comment: In CSS section, If you uncomment  //* height: 53px; *// will not work.

Comment: This is really odd, i see it's working here, but when i remove the code from mine it doesn't fix it.. but then i view the demo and that works..
I then just got rid off all other code to see if anything else was overriding it and it still didn't work.. @Vahid

Comment: @joshuaaron, Are you using bootstrap CDN ? check here: Working well in my local system and jsfiddle one. Could you please put all html file and all CSS file?

Comment: turned out i had the same set height in a media query at the bottom i had neglected to see and take out as well. So thank you for your help! Accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have overrided `navbar-default` class and added `background-color:transparent`. Just comment it and you can find it on the top of all.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hpfdsf28/1/)**

```
.navbar-default {
  /*background-color: transparent;*/
  border: 0px;
  z-index:100000;//Add this property
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't solve the problem. Here is another screenshot http://imgur.com/CB1HYpq 

It hides behind the slideshow, and on some pages it goes over if there is a div of text there like in first screenshot @GuruprasadRao

Comment: @joshuaaron Updated answer!! Add `z-index` property!!

Comment: this is a good temporary fix, it doesn't push the content below it down like it should be but is accessible for now so thanks

Comment: anytime!! Mark it as answer if it helped!! Happy Coding.. :)